# How to add server level triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers, azure-sql-database

I am new to SQL Azure and want to add a server level trigger like in normal (non-Azure) SQL Server. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Azure SQL Database Transact-SQL differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information) from Microsoft:

> **Transact-SQL syntax not supported in SQL Database**
>
> - Triggers: Server-scoped or logon triggers

So it seems you cannot create sever-level triggers on SQL in Azure.

This was also the first result on Google when I searched for `sql server azure server level triggers`, so you need to try doing at least some research yourself before posting in the future.